# Igualsr ID's de registro de usuario por metodo email al hacer push en Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Mi pregunta es como hacer para que sea igual el identificador de un registro de usuario en email y al guardar datos sea por el mismo identificador todo esto lo estoy haciendo en html y javascript el codigo es el siguiente:

```
var database = firebase.database();
var userConect = null;
var  Nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
var  Apellido = document.getElementById('apellido').value;
var  Edad = document.getElementById('edad').value;

function registro(){
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(function() {
console.log('OK');
})
```

**Hasta aqui es el codigo para crear la cuenta por email**

**Esta parte es el listener**

```
function observador() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
  console.log('Ya hay un usuario activo');
  // User is signed in.
  var displayName = user.displayName;
  var email = user.email;
  console.log(user.emailVerified);
  var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
  var uid = user.uid; 
  userConect = database.ref("users");
  AgregarDB(user.uid, user.emailVerified, Nombre, Apellido, Edad);
    function AgregarDB(Nombre,Apellido, Edad) {
      var  Nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
      var  Apellido = document.getElementById('apellido').value;
      var  Edad = document.getElementById('edad').value;

      var conectados = userConect.push({
      uid: uid,
      emailVerified: emailVerified,
      Nombre: Nombre,
      Apellido: Apellido,
      Edad: Edad
  });
}
}
```

**Todo esto es el codigo e insertare imagenes para mayor entendimiento de mi pregunta**

*imagen 1*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*imagen 2*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Quiero que la imagen key del push (DB) sea igual a la imagen 1(registro de usuario por email) key del registro de usuario*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día.

Todo lo que necesitas saber está [en la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?authuser=0). Aunque no te culpo porque no hace mención explícita del método [`child()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference?authuser=0#child) que tienen las referencias de la base de datos.

La documentación en inglés explica:

> Devuelve un `Reference` para ubicación en la ruta relativa
>   especificada.
>
> La ruta relativa puede ser un nombre de hijo simple ("ada") o una ruta
>   más profunda separada por plecas ("ada/name/firts").

*La mejor traducción de mi vida B)*

En otras palabras lo que significa es que `child(ruta)` funciona como cuando haces `database.ref(ruta)` solo que es relativo. O sea

- `.ref()` usa la ruta desde la raíz de la base de datos
- `.child()` usa la ruta desde la `Reference`.

En todo caso, podés jugar con esto. Para lograr lo que necesitas, podés hacer varias cosas, todas válidas:

```
userConect = database.ref("users");
userReferencia = database.ref("users").child(uid); // Usando child
userReferencia = database.ref("users/" + uid); // Usando la ruta profunda

userReferencia = userConect.child(uid); // Usando un Reference ya existente
userReferencia = database.ref().child("users").child("uid"); // También podés usar child en child
```

Este ultimo puede ser útil porque por motivos de orden podés tener la `Reference` de tus usuarios y la `Reference` de tu usuario específico de manera separada. Aunque es lo mismo.

Y una última nota es que cuando ya tenés tu `userReference` no hagás `push()` sino que [`set`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference?authuser=0#set) o eventualmente [`update`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference?authuser=0#update) cuando ya tengas info dentro.
Esto es porque `push` va a crear un nodo más profundo en la base de datos. Mientras que `set` va a dejar tus datos donde los necesitas. Usalo y verás a que me refiero.

Answer (score 0):

userConect = database.ref("users").child(uid); **Esta es la respuesta**

Comment: Que bien que lo encontraste. Yo ya estaba editando una respuesta. Espero que también te sea de ayuda :)